# How to change Key value pairs in JSON to XML attributes instead of nodes

Tags: c#, .net, json, xml

I am trying to change a normal JSON into an XML but instead of changing the keys of JSON to XML nodes, I want to change them to attributes. I tried the following code

`XNode node = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(kvp.ToString(), "root");`

but that gives me XML with each fields as nodes.

For example my JSON is:

`"ItemDetails": [
    {
    "ItemNo": "0001",
    "Desc": "Office Supplies",
    "Note": "",
    "Units": "20"
    }
]`

I want to change that to following. With each key as attribute and not XML nodes

`<ItemDetails ItemNo="0001" Desc="Office Supplies" Note="" Units="20"/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not out of the box using Newtonsoft. Instead, you have to create the XML with all nodes and then rewrite it moving all nodes to attributes, them removing the child nodes.

You can do this both using `XmlDocument` and `XNode`

**XNode example**

```
string json = @"{
    ""ItemDetails"": [
    {
        ""ItemNo"": ""0001"",
        ""Desc"": ""Office Supplies"",
        ""Note"": """",
        ""Units"": ""20""
    }
    ]}";

XNode node = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(json, "root");

// select all ItemDetails
var itemDetails = node.XPathSelectElements("//ItemDetails");

foreach (XElement item in itemDetails)
{
    foreach (XNode childNode in item.Nodes().ToList())
    {
        // add attribute to node
        var element = childNode as XElement;
        item.SetAttributeValue(element.Name, element.Value);

        // remove the childnode
        element.Remove();
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(node.Document.ToString());
```

Test run: https://dotnetfiddle.net/EVDwHN

**XmlDocument example**

```
string json = @"{
    ""ItemDetails"": [
    {
        ""ItemNo"": ""0001"",
        ""Desc"": ""Office Supplies"",
        ""Note"": """",
        ""Units"": ""20""
    }
    ]}";

// using xmldocument
XmlDocument doc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json, "root", true);

// select all ItemDetails
var itemDetails = doc.SelectNodes("//ItemDetails");

foreach (XmlNode item in itemDetails)
{
    foreach (XmlNode childNode in item.ChildNodes.Cast<XmlNode>().ToList())
    {
        var attribute = doc.CreateAttribute(childNode.Name);
        attribute.Value = childNode.InnerText;

        // add attribute to node
        item.Attributes.Append(attribute);

        // remove the childnode
        item.RemoveChild(childNode);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(doc.InnerXml);
```

Test run: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9HtdsU

Comment: This is the perfect answer to my question. That code was clever, clean and really easy to understand. Thank you so much Eric.

Comment: @PShrestha cool, mark it as the answer if it was what you were looking for